# Read config file from classpath in Java with default in JAR

Tags: java, properties, classloader, properties-file

UPDATE: As it turns out in some of the tests I was conducting the classpath was not being set correctly in the IDE.  The snippet below works properly.  This is no longer an issue.

I'm trying to set some properties/configurations in a text file that will be deployed inside a JAR.

I want the users to be able to supply their own properties/configurations file which will override the one used in the JAR, so the one in the JAR will only be used if the user-supplied file does not exist.

I am using Class.getResource(path), which should be able to find both relative and absolute (with a leading slash) files.

given the following file hierarchy inside the JAR:

```
<jar-file>/SomeClass.class
<jar-file>/conf/config-file.txt
```

and an optional file at

```
<some-classpath-folder>/conf/config-file.txt
```

I am trying to do something like the snippet below, so that only if the file is not found in an absolute folder conf from the classpath, it will be loaded from the relative conf folder inside the JAR:

```
Class clasz = SomeClass.class;
res = clasz.getResource("/conf/config-file.txt");    // absolute file not found, note leading-slash

if (res == null)
    res = clasz.getResource("conf/config-file.txt"); // relative file is found, No leading-slash
```

The relative file (from within the JAR) is found, but the absolute one from the classpath is not.

Calling System.getProperty("java.class.path") shows the <some-classpath-folder> folder, so it looks like the classpath is set correctly, and yet the file at <some-classpath-folder>/conf/config-file.txt is not found.

Is there a way to know which folders were scanned in search of the file?  Or any suggestions on what's going wrong here?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

If you rely solely on classpath resources you are at the mercy of the classpath hierarchy, how the program is run, etc. This *may* work, but it's not entirely within your control.

IMO it would be better to check for an explicitly-defined path, e.g., via a system property like `-Dconfig=/path/to/config`, a known location like a file in the user's home, or the properties API.

Comment: I plan to give the files unique names so that should not be an issue IMO.  I'm trying to keep the external configuration to a minimum, and this will be used in a Servlet Filter so I want to avoid user.home etc.  I will update the question with more details.  thank you.

Comment: @Igal If this is in a web app, and you want to have user-configurable options, without modifying the web app, you should still use an external file for additional configuration, IMO. Or JNDI/etc.

Comment: I will look into JNDI, but please see my update in the question which seems to me like it should be a simple solution if I could get it to work.  thanks.

Comment: @Igal The problem is that *you* don't set the classpath for your app, whoever is using the *app* does: whether or not it works is out of your hands. It's *much* more reliable to not use the classpath for user-defined things, but you can do it however you want.

Comment: I realize that your suggestions will make it more reliable, but I want to provide default configs that will apply to 99% of the cases, allowing advanced users to override the config, so the advanced users will know what the classpath folders are.  Problem is that in my testing inside IntelliJ I can find the relative file but not the absolute one.  any ideas why?

Comment: @Igal Probably because your classpath isn't what you think it is, which is further evidence it's not great to rely on this mechanism for user configs. I don't see why it's so onerous to put the defaults on the classpath and override those with properties found at a non-CP location. CP configuration can be tricky even for experienced users, they're container-dependent, they're difficult to maintain and remember, and so on. Good luck!

Comment: The thing is that calling System.getProperty("java.class.path") does show the <some-classpath-folder> folder as an entry there.  Anyway, I appreciate your time.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't on your classpath in your specific use case. I'm saying ensuring its as easy to get working across all java environments is tricky, not worth it, and more difficult to manage than other mechanisms.

Comment: you're probably right.  I will consider changing it in the future after getting some user feedback.  thanks again for your help.